# Send a method implementation as parameter

Tags: java, methods, reflection, lambda

Okay I am developing this library where I need the user to be able to implement his own implementation of a rendering method if "default" is not satisfactory, how would I do this?

I know it's possible to send functions in JavaScript and I think I need a similar construct in Java..

I have been considering lambdas and also the Method class of Java..

What would you guys say are my best alternative?

Comment: To follow a guide about Lambda, they are exactly what you want. The old way would be a [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) to pass the instance to execute it (that's basicly what the lambda will do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you would like a system wherein a person using your library can override a default algorithm with their own implementation by some means. This could look something like this:

```
public class Renderer{
    // Declare an interface which specifies a single method that handles rendering
    public interface RenderHandler{ void render(float f, float f1); }

    // Declare a default implementation that is created with each instance of the Renderer
    protected RenderHandler handler = (f, f1) -> { System.out.println("Replace me!"); };

    // Define a system of replacement for the rendering routine
    public void replaceHandler(RenderHandler replacement){
        if(replacement!=null) handler = replacement; // Determine a viable replacement
    }

    // This shows that the same method can be called but yield different results
    // based on how the RenderHandler object in the "handler" field is implemented
    public void handleRender(float f, float f1){ handler.render(f, f1); }
}
```

Now, this example would allow a user of your library to call `replaceHandler()` with a custom implementation to replace the default one that comes with the Renderer object. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Renderer r = new Renderer();                              // Create Renderer object
    r.handleRender(1f, 2f);                                   // Prints "Replace me!"
    r.replaceHandler((f, f1)->{ System.out.println(f*f1); }); // Lambda implementation
    r.handleRender(1f, 2f);                                   // Prints "2"
}
```

As you can see, the actual implementation of the replacement is handled by the person using your library (except for the default implementation). As such, you don't have to worry about *how* it's implemented, only that, in the event that a replacement is requested, it acually *is* implemented. This means that if you want to support the option for a custom rendering routine, you can do this by defining an interface with the appropriate methods and simply implement a default one and allow for replacements using a method (as demonstrated in the first code sample).